# List Categories of a post and style each by slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show the categories assigned to any post in a Wordpress site and style each category with a unique background colour using the category slug as a class name.

I've tried the code below, which shows a list of the categories for any post but duplicates the list and adds the a slug class to each list not to each category. I'm sure the duplicates are due to the two foreach loops, but I can't get either to work without error unless I have the other.

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'category');
        if($terms) {
            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                $categories = get_the_category();
                $separator = ' ';
                $output = '';
                    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
                        $cat_obj = get_term($term->term_id, 'category');
                        $cat_slug = $cat_obj->slug;
                        $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" class="post-category-' . esc_attr($cat_slug) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
                    }

            echo trim( $output, $separator );
            }
        }
    ?>
```

What I end up with is a list with the first category slug as a class and then a second list with the second category slug as a class:

```
<a href="http:site.ca/category/archive-posts/" class="post-category-archive-posts" alt="View all posts in Archive Posts">Archive Posts</a>
<a href="http://site.ca/category/making-decisions/" class="post-category-archive-posts" alt="View all posts in Decision Making">Decision Making</a>
<a href="http://site.ca/category/archive-posts/" class="post-category-making-decisions" alt="View all posts in Archive Posts">Archive Posts</a>
<a href="http:site.ca/category/making-decisions/" class="post-category-making-decisions" alt="View all posts in Decision Making">Decision Making</a>
```

Any help with how to resolve the duplicates would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to go through the category terms if you're going to loop through the available categories using a different function. Slug object property exists for the return object of `get_the_category()` too

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category();
        if(!empty( $categories)) {
                $separator = ' ';
                $output = '';
                    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
                        $cat_obj = get_term($term->term_id, 'category');
                        // $cat_slug = $cat_obj->slug;
                        $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" class="post-category-' . esc_attr($category->slug) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
                    }

            echo trim( $output, $separator );
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is already provided by `get_the_category()`. No need for all the extra loops or database queries:

```
<?php
  $the_cats = get_the_category();
  if( $the_cats ) ){
    $links = array();
    foreach( $the_cats as $the_cat ) {
      $links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $the_cat->term_id ) ) . '" class="post-category-' . esc_attr( $the_cat->slug ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $the_cat->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $the_cat->name ) . '</a>';
    }
    echo implode( ' ', $links );
  }
?>
```